# Using a CSV file with file path info (file's orginal location end with .jpg, destination end with .jpg) to copy files

Tags: csv, copy, location, shutil

I have a csv file with location information of images in 1st column
and
a destination location information of images in 2nd column

I was able to move one image to location with code

```
import shutil
source_folder = r"C:/Users/JJ/Desktop/test/images/AoF06978.jpg"
destination_folder = r"C:/Users/JJ/Desktop/new_db/test_fire/AoF06978.jpg"
shutil.copyfile(source_folder, destination_folder)
```

However, when I tried to move all files using CSV file, I have no clue;

```
import csv, shutil

filename = 'C:/Users/JJ/Desktop/test.csv'

with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in datareader:
        a= row[0]
        b =row[1]
        shutil.copyfile(a, b)
```

and I got an error: iterator should return strings, not bytes

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `.csv` file has a header, you can skip this one, then read the two columns (origin and destination) as lists and finally use [**`shutil.copyfile`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfile) to copy/move the images :

```
import csv
import shutil

with open("C:/Users/JJ/Desktop/test.csv", "r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for index, row in enumerate(reader):
        if index == 0:
            pass
        else:
            origin, destination = row
            shutil.copy(origin, destination)
```